# Color Changing for Dash Daq Thermometer/gauge/LED display

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to make an interactive dashboard with gauge/thermometer/led in it.

How can I make the color changes in them according to their updated values rather than everything in one color?

```
daq.Thermometer( 
       id ='temperature', label="Temperature", 
       value=27, max=50, min=0, showCurrentValue=True, units="C", 
       color='red',
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback taking the Thermometer value as an input and the Thermometer colour as an output.

Example below:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('temperature', 'color'),
    [Input('temperature', 'value')]
)
def update_therm_col(val):
    if val >= 20:
        return 'red'
    elif val < 20:
        return 'blue'
```

If you wanted to jazz it up a bit more you could make the colour a function of the value - the `color` parameter can take hexadecimal values as well.

Hope this helps,

Ollie

Comment: Thanks, it works. But i wonder, 'update_therm_col (val)' is a function that we define ourselves?

Comment: Yes it is. If you just copy and paste that function into your code it will work.